# Playstation 4 on a Thunderbolt display?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

Is there any way at all that I could connect a Playstation 4 to a Thunderbolt display?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't connect a Thunderbolt display to it. No adapter has ever been created to connect Thunderbolt devices to USB 3 (what the PS4 has). The performance would be horrendous and not usable even if one was ever made.

Comment: It's such a great display, too bad it's nearly unusable. :( Is there *any* way to get around this? Say, by connecting the PS4 to a mac, which in turn connects to the Thunderbolt display?

Comment: I'm not certain about a PS4's software capabilities as I don't have one, just the hardware. In theory that might be possible, but I don't know for sure.